# "pids cgroup controller not found" error when trying to create k3s node

Tags: linux, mount, kubernetes, cgroup

I am trying to create a k3s node on my QNAP NAS using the "Container Station" (= QNAP Docker runtime).

Unfortunately the container crashes with the error `FATA[0003] pids cgroup controller not found`.

I am using the latest arm image: `rancher/k3s:v1.26.2-rc1-k3s1-arm-data-1`.

This is the start-up log of the container:

```
WARN[0000] cgroup2 is not mounted. cgroup2 evacuation is discarded. 
INFO[0000] Starting k3s agent v1.26.2-rc1+k3s1 (ea094d1d) 
INFO[0000] Running load balancer k3s-agent-load-balancer 127.0.0.1:6444 -> [x.x.x.x:6443] 
WARN[0002] Failed to load kernel module overlay with modprobe 
INFO[0002] Module nf_conntrack was already loaded       
INFO[0002] Module br_netfilter was already loaded       
INFO[0002] Module iptable_nat was already loaded        
WARN[0002] Failed to load kernel module iptable_filter with modprobe 
W0305 16:26:15.037751      17 sysinfo.go:203] Nodes topology is not available, providing CPU topology
INFO[0002] Logging containerd to /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/containerd.log 
INFO[0002] Running containerd -c /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/config.toml -a /run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock --state /run/k3s/containerd --root /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd 
INFO[0003] containerd is now running                    
INFO[0003] Getting list of apiserver endpoints from server 
INFO[0003] Updating load balancer k3s-agent-load-balancer default server address -> x.x.x.x:6443 
INFO[0003] Connecting to proxy                           url="wss://x.x.x.x:6443/v1-k3s/connect"
WARN[0003] Disabling CPU quotas due to missing cpu controller or cpu.cfs_period_us 
FATA[0003] pids cgroup controller not found
```

On the host system the followng cgroups are mounted:

```sh
[~] # cat /proc/mounts | grep cgroup
cgroup_root /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,relatime,memory 0 0
cpu /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,relatime,name=systemd 0 0
```

How can I fix the error?